# What is the true definition of tirtzach?

Tags: hebrew, mitzvah

In Hebrew, the word tirtzach is normally translated to mean murder. In English, murder means unlawful premeditated killing. But if this is the definition of tirtzach, then the commandment lo tirtzach would be a truism, since it would mean “do not make an unlawful premeditated killing”, which essentially means “it is illegal to do a premeditated killing in an illegal manner”.

So what is the true definition of tirtzach?

Comment: Is "do not steal" also a truism because "steal" means to take something illegally?